# Efficient acceleration at the start in Alpine Ski Racing 2007

Tags: alpine-ski-racing-2007

I can't figure out how to accelerate at the start of the race in this game [Alpine Ski Racing 2007](http://games.gamepressure.com/game.asp?ID=606)

There are 2 kinds of acceleration: (i) acceleration at the starting position when the skier works with his poles (ii) acceleration after the start when the skier takes a tuck aerodynamic position (this 2nd type of acceleration is regulated by pressing a keyboard button).

This image demonstrates the starting position[image]

There are 2 indicators on the right. The grey indicator shows time left before the start. According to Brutus's answer and this you tube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Znj6gqbpPos)  the yellow indicator shows the possible acceleration strength.

Since there are not any special buttons to regulate the first type of acceleration I thought that the button which regulates type (ii) acceleration also regulates type (i). For example depending on the yellow indicator pressing the acceleration key and holding it will determine the efficiency of starting acceleration to some degree. However I usually get only 0-2% efficiency, and only in very rare cases 4-18%. But I never got more than 18%.

I also tried pressing every button listed in game Options.

> Q: How to accelerate with efficiency close to 100% at the start of the game?

The official website for this game: http://www.alpineskiracing2007.com/

Googling this problem didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/VTn3k-O-oPk?t=63) on YouTube. Despite the start of the player is very quick, it seems to me that the yellow bar continuously goes up and down and it reaches the top just for a very short time.

You need to press the "start button" (sorry, I don't know exactly how the game works) during that short period of time, so that you maximize the starting acceleration.

Hope it helps, let me know if it works as I said!

Comment: Do you see the bar going up and down before starting?

Comment: Yes. I finally figured out that the start button is the left mouse click.